# Node.js beginner struggling with arrays, promises and Async

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous

A node.js (and coding in general) beginner here, struggling with the async nature of node.  I'm trying to write some code that will look up the members of certain AD groups and add the member names to an array, as per the "getMembers" function below.  I'm only interested in computer objects, which is why I only have ad.find returning "other" objects.

Once that is complete, I want the "processAssets" function to do something with the array - for the purpose of testing, just ouptutting to the console.log.  The problem is that "processAssets" is running before "getMembers" has populated the array.  What am I doing wrong?  I realise the answer may begin with "several things"...!

```
const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
var query = 'memberOf=cn=';
var cNames = [
        'group1',
        'group2',
        'group3'
        ];
var baseOu = ',ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com';
function run(cNames) {
    Promise.all(cNames.map(cName => getMembers(cName))).then(processAssets())
}

async function getMembers(cName) {
    await ad.find(query + cName + baseOu, async function(err, results) {
        if ((err) || (! results)) {return;}
        await _.each(results.other, function(other) {
            assetArray.push(other.cn);
        });
    });
}

function processAssets() {
    console.log("Contents of assetArray (" + assetArray.length + " assets):");
    assetArray.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `.find` returns a `Promise`? It looks to be callback-based.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using the activedirectory package, not ad directly.  I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: So, are you sure that `.find` returns a `Promise`?

Comment: No I'm not sure - as I said I'm a beginner, and despite researching this website and others I feel I've missed something fundamental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some things mixed up.

The main problem causing your immediate issue is this line:

```
Promise.all(cNames.map(cName => getMembers(cName))).then(processAssets())
```

You need to pass a function to `then()` which will be called when the promise resolves. You are not doing that, you are passing it the result of calling `processAssets()`, which has the effect of calling `processAssets()` immediately. Typically you would us something like:

```
Promise.all(cNames.map(cName => getMembers(cName))).then(() => processAssets())
/*                                                       ^^ pass a function  */
```

Additionally you are `await` things for no purpose. There's no reason to await here:

```
 await ad.find(query + cName + baseOu, async function(err, results) {
```

`ad.find` doesn't return a promise. In general functions that take callbacks don't return promises (maybe there are some exceptions, but I can't think of any). If you want to have a promise to use in `run()`'s `Promise.all` you need to wrap the `find` function in a promise and return it. Something like:

```
function getMembers(cName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ad.find(query + cName + baseOu, function(err, results) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      // I'm making some assumptions about results. But hopefully this gives
      // a good enough idea
      let data = results.other.map(other => other.cn)
      resolve(data)
      });
  });  
}
```

Now `getMembers` returns a promise that resolves to the result of `ad.find` and you can use it in `Promise.all.